# MySQL selecting distinct value not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

I am trying to retrieve distinct value using this query from my salary table

```
SELECT DISTINCT gross,sl_month,sl_year 
FROM wp_attn_emp_salary where `emp_id` = 22 order by gross DESC
```

But it returns duplicate value too. please, check the image.

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEfuD.jpg)

My expecting result is like this

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 9595
        [sl_month] => 2
        [sl_year] => 2021
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 9226
        [sl_month] => 1
        [sl_year] => 2020
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 8875
        [sl_month] => 2
        [sl_year] => 2019
    
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 8420
        [sl_month] => 1
        [sl_year] => 2019
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 8405
        [sl_month] => 12
        [sl_year] => 2018
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [gross] => 6464
        [sl_month] => 1
        [sl_year] => 2018
    )

)
```

I need the sl_month,sl_year in descending order too.

Comment: Distinct is over all selected columns and I see no duplicates on the link - which do you think are duplicates?

Comment: Your are selecting everything `where `emp_id` = 22`.  So SQL will show all rows. When you want to show only the last year/month per `gross` you can do this by using `GROUP BY` and some [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstand how DISTINCT works in SQL. It returns a row if the whole row (i.e. all columns) is distinct from any other row in the result. These two rows are distinct from each other:

| gross | sl_month | sl_year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9595 | 1 | 2021 |
| 9595 | 2 | 2021 |

From the desired result you described, it looks like you want a [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) query.

```
SELECT gross, sl_month, sl_year
FROM (
 SELECT gross, sl_month, sl_year,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY gross ORDER BY sl_year, sl_month) AS rownum
 FROM wp_attn_emp_salary 
 WHERE emp_id = 22
) AS t
WHERE t.rownum = 1
ORDER BY sl_month DESC, sl_year DESC;
```

Note: [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) require MYSQL 8.0, which was released in 2018 so you should be using it by now. If you need a solution that runs on an earlier version of MySQL, search past answers with the [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) tag.

Comment: hello @Bill the solution is not working for me as now it's not possible to migrate to MySQL 8.0. Would you be able to give any other solution? I need it too badly.

Comment: I already gave you advice on what to do if you have not upgraded to MySQL 8.0.